# google cloud Kubernetes yum repository is EMPTY

Tags: kubernetes, yum

We are used to use this repository to download kubelet and kubeadm packages - https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/Packages
but it's unavailable now, I mean it's empty from RPMs since yesterday.
Can't find those rpms anywhere online and also there is not a status page or update from google that they are taking it down.

The kubernetes documentation still points to this entry and it's empty.
ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RPMs for Kubernetes do not exist anymore on https://packages.cloud.google.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881976/rpms-for-kubernetes-do-not-exist-anymore-on-https-packages-cloud-google-com)

Answer (score 1):

> The Kubernetes documentation still points to this entry and it's empty.

Actually this [page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl) (The Official Kubernetes Installation Guide) explains that.

> ideas ?

The guide suggests adding the repo under the the list of YUM repos. I have been installing k8s components from the following source with no issues.

```
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kubelet kubeadm kubectl
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be there just fine for me, https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/Packages/29e7806d1d54cc0eea2963f4ab276778526538816c88c963ece7d1a05fd80792-cri-tools-1.0.0_beta.1-0.x86_64.rpm for example. If you just mean the web server doesn't show the file list for those folders, yes because it's huge.